# Prevent AWS Cognito sign up spam attacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-cognito

We have an application which provides user authentication via AWS Cognito. This morning it was reported by users that they weren't receiving the MFA SMS to log in. When we investigated, we found that someone had spammed thousands of signups to Cognito (~700 per 5 minutes) with random emails/phone numbers until our account hit the SMS spend limit and SMS deliveries started failing.

We're trying to figure out the best way to avoid this in the future. I was surprised that Cognito does not provide any sort of sign up spam protection against an attack like this, but that's my fault for not knowing that.

What are our options? I can see that I can use AWS WAF to provide rate limiting but it looks like the minimum rate limit is 100 requests per 5 minutes, which would have still let the attacker use up all of our quota before we realised.

We can set up alarms etc to notify us of unusual usage, but we're not running a massive application and certainly don't have 24 hour coverage of these things so even if we had this, we would have missed it.

What other options do we have? Should we set up a pre-signup custom Lambda hook and do custom rate limiting ourselves? We could do this but it feels like a lot of work since we'd need to store requests to a database etc so we can check if it's being hit too much. Is there anything else we can try?

Comment: Were you able to find any available options for this case?

Comment: Unfortunately we didn't find any strong solutions. We contacted AWS support and they said this:

I would like to share that unfortunately AWS doesn't support any account/region/country based SMS spending throttles. There is no way to restrict sending messages as you are using the SNS resources to deliver the message. Depending on how we are sending messages, we can use a pinpoint phone validate API and based on output response we can set custom logic to stop sending SMS messages to some of the country. For more information on pinpoint phone validate API you may refer below documentation.

Comment: [+] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/validate-phone-numbers.html#validate-phone-numbers-request  

We could prevent such flood attack by integrating other AWS services with Cognito like WAF (Web Application Firewall) and Amazon Fraud Detector.

Comment: We also mitigated the issue by adding a pre-signup lambda function where we put in a few regexes to block signups using the email/phone number patterns the user was using. We haven't had any more issues since - we assume this was just an opportunistic attack by a bored person.

We also realised that we could set the SMS spend limit below the total authorised limit for the account, so if it happens again we can mitigate it and then just increase the SMS limit without having to wait for AWS support.

Comment: Thank you for this extended answer. Yeah, we also agreed to use pre-signup lambda hook with extra validation + AWS WAF deployment, based on recomendations provided https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/protect-your-amazon-cognito-user-pool-with-aws-waf/